# MapPath vs VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using c#, asp.net and working on a web application.

I initially had a relative path as such which I needed to be an absolute path.
The below works but need to get the absolute path:

```
    return Chart.RenderChartHTML("../../Charts/MSLine.swf");
```

I tried the following which didn't work (note that it gives me the complete path on my hard drive to .swf):

```
    string mslinepath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Charts/MSLine.swf");

    return Chart.RenderChartHTML(mslinepath);
```

I then tried the following which works:

```
    string mslinepath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Charts/MSLine.swf");

    return Chart.RenderChartHTML(mslinepath);
```

Wondering why VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute works while the other one doesn't.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`MapPath` returns the physical file path on your server which corresponds to the specified virtual path.
*(Eg: "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Charts\MSLine.swf")*

`ToAbsolute` converts an app-relative virtual path (one starting with "~/") to an absolute virtual path.
*(Eg: "/AppName/Charts/MSLine.swf")*

Comment: Thanks but do you know why one would work while the other one didn't

Comment: Because the `RenderChartHTML` method expects a virtual path, and `MapPath` returns a physical path.